# What should I do about an old question that I'm not interested in finding an answer for?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted the following question about a year ago:

[DB2 Query Error SQL0204N Even With The Schema Defined](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65818/db2-query-error-sql0204n-even-with-the-schema-defined)

It went unanswered and I have since stopped using DB2. I don't even have DB2 installed any more.

However, the question received a recent comment and has two upvotes and one favorite.

My question is should I ask the moderators to delete the question (or delete it myself – I don't know if this is possible) or should I just edit the question, adding that I don't use DB2 anymore and can't really try any solutions.

Thoughts?

Comment: I've deleted the answer that wasn't very useful - I think that means you can now delete the question if you choose to do so.

Comment: @JackDouglas  Thank you Jack. I've deleted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have left the question to be answered in the future, if not for you, maybe for others.

I'll give you some reasons:

- maybe in the future someone will habe the same problem and would be grateful for an answer
- the question has already sparked some interest (the comments and the favorite show this), thus someone is interested in an answer

Comment: Great point.  I probably hit delete a little too quickly.  My reasoning was that I didn't want a "ghost question" hanging around and I'm not even capable of trying or verifying an answer that was posted.

Comment: @Jesuisme You do have a 'grace period' where you can undelete questions. If you want to put the question back, I think you still can. Go to your profile, click on questions, and on the bottom it should say recently deleted questions.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Ressurrected!!  Thanks!